# What does the writer mean by "ocean foam" in this context and is it a common phrase and meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've never heard the phrase "ocean foam" used in this manner, so I'm not sure of it's meaning. I think I can gather *a little* from the context, but I'd like to know for sure. I can only find the literal meaning from [online searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ocean+foam%22+meaning&client=firefox-b-d&ei=INhpYNbiKpij1fAPxa6Y8As&oq=%22ocean+foam%22+meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAgQHlDMPligVWCeWmgAcAJ4AIABiwKIAf4DkgEFMy4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjW8uPw8OTvAhWYURUIHUUXBr4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5).

(An Observatory Telephotographer (Beenay 25) is talking to a newspaper columnist (Theremon 762) at a scientific observatory during a possibly catastrophic eclipse when stars may be seen for the first time)

> But Beenay had drawn his chair closer, and there was  an expression  of
> sudden  enthusiasm  on  his  face.  'Say, I'm  glad  you two  got onto  this
> subject.' His eyes narrowed  and he  lifted one finger. 'I've been  thinking
> about these Stars and I've got a really cute notion. Of course it's strictly **ocean foam**, and I'm not trying to advance it seriously, but I think it's interesting. Do you want to hear it?

From the short story [*"Nightfall"*](http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/fwalter/AST389/TEXTS/Nightfall.htm) written in the US in 1940 by a 20-year-old Isaac Asimov. Probably in Brooklyn, New York.
(I'm reading a 1974 "Best of" publication)

From there, the character talks about his scientific speculation, which is seemingly wondrous, maybe even far-fetched from *his* point of view but to the reader, It's familiar and factual (i.e. The idea of a planet orbiting a single sun, thus having a period of night).

As well as the meaning, I'd also like to know...

- Was it a well-used phrase and meaning at the time of writing?
- Is this phrase and meaning still in use today?

Comment: Hello @Lambie ... I added more

Comment: Ocean foam ... flying a kite ... bouncing an idea ...

Comment: "Not everything" is a phrase ... is it not? @Lambie :)

Comment: I was thinking it may be a "food for thought" sort-of-thing. I was hoping somebody might have heard/read it before in a similar context or know for sure what it means.

Comment: I think it has more the connotation of “insubstantial” rather than food for thought.

Comment: It is a nonce term, probably the equivalent of "spitballing"...in this case, "ocean foam" refers to something  frothy, and short-lived.

Comment: @James Yeah, I thought about "speculative", it's more formal because *he is* a type of scientist. None of it relates to ocean foam though.

Comment: @Cascabel surely a nonce term would make clear sense though. It does, sort of, now I think about it. As ocean foam blowing around, off the sea, and "short-lived" as you say.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_foam. "Ocean foam" is used metaphorically - there is no more to it than that. The foam itself is exceptionally light and structurally weak.

Comment: Not everything is a pre-existing phrase that you can google. That's what creative writing is. And the preceding text would be useful. Ocean foam is more than hot air.

Comment: From the context, *ocean foam* is simply another way of saying [*froth*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/froth) — which figuratively means *an insubstantial idea*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it was not a common phrase in 1974.  I have never heard it used in the past 60 years.

It sounds like a phrase that Beenay coined, and he expected the reader to grok its meaning from the context, as you did.  Ocean foam is not solid, it does not have a solid structure, and he was using it as a metaphor for his hypothesis on the matter.

Comment: It would have been 1940, when it was written

Comment: But yeah, that "structure" metaphor makes sense from a scientific perspective (The writer completed his MA in chemistry around the same time of writing). So it would make sense he'd use a term like this to describe a theoretical postulation or speculation that might not hold up under examination.